# How do I get a CGAffineTransformMakeScale to shrink a view around its center?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, core-graphics, affinetransform

This should be an easy one -- when I use a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` on a `UIView` with `width = 0.5` and `height = 0.5`, it shrinks to the upper left.  I need it to shrink around its center.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to turn off Autolayout if you are experiencing the same behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Aha, figured this one out.  I was doing some custom drawing and had mixed up frame and bounds.

Comment: Hi, could you expand on your answer/question? This question is highly ranked on the Google. The whole world is watching ;)

Comment: just save the center before you set the new transform, and then set that center back once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

By default CGAffineTransformMakeScale *will* scale UIViews around their center.

For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
}  completion:nil ];
```

.. will make the myView twice the size, scaled around its center.